# GridLayout for secondery panels in the main panel JAVA Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I create this program and use panels for every info the user insert.
But al the panels sit side by side . i want to get all the smalls panels like Gender,Weight and Body Frame one below the other and the Height and Personal Data panels side by side.

And under to all of this panels i want to put the Calculate button.
itried some types of gridlayout but nothing is like what i want.

Photo of how it looks now:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WUQ9.png]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Hashtable;


public class bmi {
    private static JFrame testFrame;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private final String[] genderComboTexts={"Male","Female"};
    private JComboBox genderChoices=null;
    private JSlider ageSlider;
    private JSlider heightSlider;
    private final String[] bodyComboTexts={"Small","Medium","Large"};
    private JComboBox bodyFrame=null;

    private JTextField nameTF;
    private JTextField fnameTF;
    private JTextField ageTF;
    private JTextField weightTF;

    public bmi() {

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(initPersonalDataAndPanel());
        mainPanel.add(initGenderPanel());
        mainPanel.add(initHeightSlider());
        mainPanel.add(initWeightPanel());
        mainPanel.add(initBodyFrame());
        JButton calc = new JButton("Calculate");
        mainPanel.add(calc);
     
        calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                double height = heightSlider.getValue();
                double age =Double.parseDouble(ageTF.getText());
                double weight=Double.parseDouble((weightTF.getText()));

                double heightM=height/100;
                double bmi = weight/(Math.pow(heightM,2));
                System.out.println("BMI: "+new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(bmi));

                if(bmi<15){
                    System.out.println("You are Anorexic");
                }
                else if(bmi>15 && bmi<18.5){
                    System.out.println("You are Underweight");
                }
                else if(bmi>18.5 && bmi<24.9){
                    System.out.println("You are Normal");
                }
                else if(bmi>25.0 && bmi<29.9){
                    System.out.println("You are Overweight");
                }
                else if(bmi>30.0 && bmi<35){
                    System.out.println("You are Obese");
                }
                else if(bmi>35){
                    System.out.println("You are Extreme Obese");
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private JPanel initWeightPanel(){
        JPanel panel =new JPanel();
        weightTF=new JTextField();
        weightTF.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
        panel.add(weightTF);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Weight"),
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,50,5,50)));
        return panel;
    }
    private JPanel initHeightSlider(){
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        JLabel weight=new JLabel("160");
        heightSlider=new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL,140,190,160);
        heightSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        heightSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
        heightSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        Hashtable<Integer,JLabel> labels=new Hashtable<>();
        labels.put(140, new JLabel("140"));
        labels.put(150, new JLabel("150"));
        labels.put(160, new JLabel("160"));
        labels.put(170, new JLabel("170"));
        labels.put(180, new JLabel("180"));
        labels.put(190, new JLabel("190"));
        heightSlider.setLabelTable(labels);
        heightSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        panel.add(weight);
        panel.add(heightSlider);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Height"),
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5)));
        heightSlider.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                
                weight.setText(""+heightSlider.getValue());
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        });
        return panel;
    }


    private JPanel initBodyFrame(){

        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        bodyFrame=new JComboBox(bodyComboTexts);
        panel.add(bodyFrame);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Body Frame"),
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5)));
        return panel;
    }
    private JPanel initGenderPanel(){
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        genderChoices=new JComboBox(genderComboTexts);
        panel.add(genderChoices);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Gender"),
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5)));
        return panel;
    }
    private JPanel initPersonalDataAndPanel(){
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        JLabel name=new JLabel("Name");
        JLabel fname=new JLabel("Last Name");
        JLabel age=new JLabel("Age");
        nameTF=new JTextField();
        fnameTF=new JTextField();
        ageTF= new JTextField();
        JButton print=new JButton("Print");

panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2,10,10));
        panel.add(name);
        panel.add(nameTF);
        panel.add(fname);
        panel.add(fnameTF);
        panel.add(age);
        panel.add(ageTF);
        panel.add(print);
        panel.add(new JLabel());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Personal Data"),
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5)));
        print.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                double height = heightSlider.getValue();
                double age =Double.parseDouble(ageTF.getText());
                double weight=Double.parseDouble((weightTF.getText()));



                System.out.println("Name: "+nameTF.getText());
                System.out.println("Last Name: "+fnameTF.getText());
                System.out.println("Age: "+ageTF.getText());
                System.out.println("Height: "+heightSlider.getValue());
                System.out.print("Weight: "+weightTF.getText());

                if (bodyFrame.getSelectedItem() == "Small") {
                    double idealWeight = ((height - 100 + (age / 10)) * 0.9 * 0.9);
                    System.out.println(" ====== Ideal Weight: "+new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(idealWeight));
                } else if (bodyFrame.getSelectedItem() == "Medium") {
                    double idealWeight = ((height - 100 + (age / 10)) * 0.9 * 1);
                    System.out.println(" ====== Ideal Weight: "+new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(idealWeight));
                } else if (bodyFrame.getSelectedItem() == "Large") {
                    double idealWeight = ((height - 100 + (age / 10)) * 0.9 * 1.1);
                    System.out.println(" ====== Ideal Weight: "+new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(idealWeight));
                }

                System.out.println("Gender: "+genderChoices.getSelectedItem());
                System.out.println("Body Frame: "+bodyFrame.getSelectedItem());

            }
        });
        return panel;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        bmi bmi_1 =new bmi();
        testFrame=new JFrame("Test");
        testFrame.setContentPane(bmi_1.mainPanel);
testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
testFrame.pack();
testFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: *But all the panels sit side by side* -  The default layout manager for a JPanel is the FlowLayout.  The layout for all your panels is wrong. *i want all the smalls panels like Gender,Weight and Body Frame one below the other and the Height and Personal Data panels side by side.* - don't know what that means. Draw an ascii drawing showing how you want the panel positioned relative to one another. Or use a simple paint application to demonstrate the layout. In the meantime read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: What I would do is to nest some of the panels in other panels. For example, the small inputs could be put into a panel with a BoxLayout. Or you could use a single panel with a GridBagLayout, but that can be tedious.

Answer (score 0):

So, you should do something like this
Create BorderLayout. South of the border layout should be the button Calculate.
Next, create BoxLayout JPanel with vertical allign like this.

```java
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Add Gender, Weight and BodyFrame inside it.
And create another JPanel with FlowLayout. Add Height and Personal Data inside it.

Depening on how you want this to panels to show up, you can either wrap them in FlowLayout JPanel or BoxLayout JPanel and add that to center of firstly created BorderLayout.